# удалить из строки русские буквы

Tags: c++, строки, stl

Имеется строка:

```
string str = { "hey, Johnny, how is твои дела?" };
```

нужно избавиться от "русского хвоста".
Делаю так, но почему-то строка остается неизменной

```
void delRussian(string& str)
{
    auto i = find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char& a) {
        return a >= 128;//начало русских букв в ASCII
    });

    str.erase(i, str.end());
}
```

Пробовал и так

```
void delRussian(string& str)
{
    auto i = find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char& a) {
        return (a >= 'А' && a <= 'ё');//начало русских букв в ASCII
    });

    str.erase(i, str.end());
}
```

Ни в какую.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подозреваю, что char в вашей системе - знаковый. В таком случае условие a >= 128 никогда не сработает (ибо максимальное целое число, представимое char в таком случае - 127).

Предлагаю такую модификацию:

```
void delRussian(string& str)
{
    auto i = find_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char& a) {
        return static_cast<unsigned char>(a) >= 128;//начало русских букв в ASCII
    });

    str.erase(i, str.end());
}
```

То есть преобразовываем значение к беззнаковому, а потом уж сравниваем.

Или можно преобразовать условие к такому:

!(a > 0 && a <= 127)

Comment: Да, помогло, спасибо большое!